# How to Map a Pacman Maze Using 2D Array

Tags: c++, mapping, pacman

I have created a map (experimental) which has a '#' value if there is a Boundry Wall in the maze. Laying the Map Graphically I use a checking condition that if the value of the 2D array is a # then put an image in that cell. But the Problem is That How will i know Know where to put the image on the screen (**The Pixel Position of the Screen**).

Comment: Could you give the x&y sizes of the ghosts and your pacman sprite and size of the borders ?

Comment: i havent created them yet but i suppose they will be same in size and a little smaller than the border size and spaces. border snd spaces will be the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply multiply the x position by the width of your graphics tile and the y position by its height...?

Comment: If the size of the borders are different height and width (they they most likely are) to the size of the empty spaces where actual sprites (pun!) then that does not really produce what the op is asking..

Comment: @ras: I have never seen a Pacman game with differently sized borders. Can you provide a link or picture?